# Converting List with string to json pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with an input schema like

```
 |-- runName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- action_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- model_payload: string (nullable = true)
 |-- model_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- did_pass: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ymd: string (nullable = false)
```

Inside model_payload is a list containing a json and I want to pull out the data from here and create a separate dataframe for it. However at the moment model_payload is a string.

```
root
 |-- dataset_A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dataset_B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ks_statistic: double (nullable = true)
 |-- pvalue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- rejected_hypothesis: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- target_ks_statistic: double (nullable = true)
 |-- target_pvalue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- action: string (nullable = true)
```

Where the json in model payload looks like

```
d = {
    "dataset_A": str,
    "dataset_B": str,
    "ks_statistic": str,
    "pvalue": str,
    "rejected_hypothesis": bool,
    "target_ks_statistic": str,
    "target_pvalue": str,
}
```

The only solution I've found so far is to transform this to a pandas dataframe and use json.loads(). However this is very slow and not suitable for large datasets

Comment: what is the schema of the input ? shema of the expected output ? what have you tried ? what are your pain point ?

Comment: Ive updated the question with a bit more context. Hopefully that helps. The long and short is I have a json (stored as a string in model_payload) that I want to pull out into a separate dataframe

Comment: the final output has 8 fields. The payload only 7. Where does the last one come from ?

Comment: Is it being slow the only problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your payload, you have to create the struct in pyspark and use it to parse your data.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T


schm = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("dataset_A", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("dataset_B", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("ks_statistic", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("pvalue", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("rejected_hypothesis", T.BooleanType()),
        T.StructField("target_ks_statistic", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("target_pvalue", T.StringType()),
    ]
)


df.withColumn("model_payload", F.from_json("model_payload", schm)).select(
    "model_payload.*"
)
```

Comment: This worked, although I had to add the column
```
df.withColumn("model_payload",(F.from_json("model_payload", schm).alias("model_payload"))).select(
    "model_payload.*"
)
```